# How to undo the focus on one edittext and have focus on second eddittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to manipulate with two Edittext widgets, in such a way that either I write in any Edittext first or second, it corresponding info must be written in other Edittext. Here is my code snippet:
textWatcher1 = new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            s1 = et1.getText().toString();
            if(!s1.equals("")){
                et2.setText(s1);
            } else {
                et2.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
    textWatcher2 = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            s1 = et1.getText().toString();
            if(!s1.equals("")){
                et2.setText(s1);
            }else {
                et2.setText("");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
    et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                et1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher1);
                et2.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

    et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                et2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher2);
                et1.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher1);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

But the problem is it works only for first Edittext only, when I want to write in second Edittext then application crashes. So how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have `et1` and `et2` mixed up in `TextWatcher2`.   Try --

```
  textWatcher2 = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            s1 = et2.getText().toString();
            if(!s1.equals("")){
                et1.setText(s1);
            }else {
                et1.setText("");
            }
        }
```